# Perform same function on different element depending on which is clicked - Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I have 3 `paper-input` fields used for passwords, each with a clear icon linked via `on-click` to its own unique function - all of which perform the same task but to their respective inputs.

Is there any way in which I can re-write this such that I only have 1 function that will know which input to clear, depending on which clear icon I click?

**HTML**

```
<paper-input id="currentPassword" label="Current Password">
    <div suffix id="icons1" class="input-icons1">
        <paper-icon-button icon="clear" id="clear" class="clear1" on-click="clearData1"></paper-icon-button>
    </div>
</paper-input>

<paper-input id="newPassword" label="New Password">
    <div suffix id="icons2" class="input-icons2">
        <paper-icon-button icon="clear" id="clear" class="clear2" on-click="clearData2"></paper-icon-button>
    </div>
</paper-input>

<paper-input id="confirmPassword" label="Confirm New Password" on-input="passMatch">
    <div suffix id="icons3" class="input-icons3">
        <paper-icon-button icon="clear" id="clear" class="clear3" on-click="clearData3"></paper-icon-button>
    </div>
</paper-input>
```

**JS**

```
 clearData1 : function() {
      this.$.currentPassword.value = '';
  },

  clearData2 : function() {
      this.$.newPassword.value = '';
  },

  clearData3 : function() {
      this.$.confirmPassword.value = '';
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by setting an attribute on your `paper-icon-button` which identifies the input target.

```
<paper-input id="newPassword" label="Current Password">...</paper-input>
<paper-input id="currentPassword" label="Current Password">...</paper-input>

<paper-icon-button 
  icon="clear" 
  input="newPassword" 
  on-tap="clearData">
</paper-icon-button>

<paper-icon-button 
  icon="clear" 
  input="currentPassword" 
  on-tap="clearData">
</paper-icon-button>
```

In your JS, you can get the input attribute and set the respective value:

```
clearData: function (event) {
    var idOfInput = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('input');
    this.$$('#' + idOfInput).value = '';
}
```

Clear all inputs:

```
clearAll: function () {
    var allInputs = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll('paper-icon-button'); // or certain class .btn-class
    allInputs.forEach(function (input) {
        input.value = '';
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @JFathi! I knew it was something like this, but I couldn't get it down in code. You will make me clean up lots of code :-D

Comment: I forgot to ask in my initial question...

Is there a way of clearing ALL of the inputs? Say I have an third paper-button called "clear all"...

Comment: Thanks @JFathi! <3

Answer (score 0):

hi yes you can find out which element was clicked by checking the event which is injected in you handler

#### HTML

```
<paper-input id="currentPassword" label="Current Password">
    <div suffix id="icons1" class="input-icons1">
        <paper-icon-button icon="clear" id="clear1" class="clear1" on-tap="clearData"></paper-icon-button>
</div>
</paper-input>

<paper-input id="newPassword" label="New Password">
    <div suffix id="icons2" class="input-icons2">
        <paper-icon-button icon="clear" id="clear2" class="clear2" on-tap="clearData"></paper-icon-button>
    </div>
</paper-input>

<paper-input id="confirmPassword" label="Confirm New Password" on-input="passMatch">
    <div suffix id="icons3" class="input-icons3">
        <paper-icon-button icon="clear" id="clear3" class="clear3" on-tap="clearData"></paper-icon-button>
    </div>
</paper-input>
```

#### js

```
clearData: function(event) {
   var that = this;//needed for closure
   event.path.forEach(function(item){
       if(item.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "paper-icon-button") {
          if(item.id === "clear1") {
              that.$.currentPassword.setAttribute('value', '');
          } else if(item.id === "clear2") {
              that.$.newPassword.setAttribute('value', '');
          } else if(item.id === "clear3") {
              that.$.confirmPassword.setAttribute('value', '');
          }
       }
   });
}
```